# Generate a list with a head based on object property in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, lodash

In Vue, i'm trying to generate a list based on a property in an object.
I have an array coming from the vuex store that looks like this:

```
const array = [
 { 
   name: "British title string"
   nationality: "British"
 },
 { 
   name: "Another title"
   nationality: "American"
 },
 { 
   name: "Name"
   nationality: "Dutch"
 },
{ 
   name: "Another american item"
   nationality: "American"
 },
];
```

What i want to have is the output like this using v-for:

```
<h2>British</h2>
<ul>
   <li>British title string</li>
</ul>

<h2>American</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Another title</li>
   <li>Another american item</li>
</ul>

<h2>Dutch</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Name</li>
</ul>
```

I have already sorted the array by the `nationality` property using lodash _.sortBy and it's given me an array sorted by nationality but i want to add a H2 element with the value of nationality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple items with same nationality and you want to group them up, use `_.groupBy()` before `_.sortBy()`:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#appTemplate',
  data: () => ({
    rawData: [{
        name: "British title string",
        nationality: "British"
      },
      {
        name: "Another title",
        nationality: "American"
      },
      {
        name: "Name",
        nationality: "Dutch"
      },
      {
        name: "Another american item",
        nationality: "American"
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    groupedItems() {
      return _.sortBy(
        _.map(
          _.groupBy(this.rawData, 'nationality'), 
          items => ({
            items,
            nationality: items[0].nationality
          })
        ), 
        ['nationality']
      );
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="appTemplate">
  <div>
    <template v-for="group in groupedItems">
      <h2 v-text="group.nationality" />
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in group.items" :key="index" v-text="item.name" />
      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

For convenience and data readability, I mapped first item's `nationality` as the group's nationality (and named the grouped items `items`), but you could have used item `0`'s nationality in the template directly, instead.
To demonstrate, here's how that would have looked like:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#appTemplate',
  data: () => ({
    rawData: [{
        name: "British title string",
        nationality: "British"
      },
      {
        name: "Another title",
        nationality: "American"
      },
      {
        name: "Name",
        nationality: "Dutch"
      },
      {
        name: "Another american item",
        nationality: "American"
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    groupedItems() {
      return _.sortBy(
        _.groupBy(this.rawData, 'nationality'), 
        ['0.nationality']
      );
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="appTemplate">
  <div>
    <template v-for="grouped in groupedItems">
      <h2 v-text="grouped[0].nationality" />
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in grouped" :key="index" v-text="item.name" />
      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Note both of the above examples output the required markup. If you want each item to have its own wrapper, replace `<template>` with an html tag and add keys. i.e:

```
<article v-for="(grouped, key) in groupedItems" :key="key">
```

Comment: If you also want the names sorted inside each group list, replace `this.rawData` with `_.sortBy(this.rawData, 'name')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, considering that the array is ordered:

```
    const array = [
      {
        name: "Another title",
        nationality: "American"
      },
      {
        name: "Another american item",
        nationality: "American"
      },
      {
        name: "British title string",
        nationality: "British"
      },
      {
        name: "Name",
        nationality: "Dutch"
      },

    ];
    const arrayAux = [];
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length;) {
      console.log(array[i].name);
      arrayAux.push({
        nationality: array[i].nationality,
        names: [array[i].name]
      });
      i++;
      while ( i < array.length && array[i].nationality === array[i - 1].nationality) {
        arrayAux[j].names.push(array[i].name);
        i++;
      }
      j++;

    }
    console.log(arrayAux);
```

In the html:

```
<div v-for="item in arrayAux">
  <h2>{{ item.nationality }}</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in item.names">
      {{ n.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```